# Chrome not compiling java script correctly on ubuntu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ubuntu

I am facing some serious web page rendering issues with Chrome. It is more prominent during javascript based animations and stuff on websites like youtube. I have tried removing chrome using (sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable) and then reinstalling it. But the problems still persist. The same webpages work correctly on firefox on ubuntu and chrome on windows. The problem only shows up when I use chrome on ubuntu.

I think the issue has started after I updated to the latest version of Chrome. I have used Chrome previously on this machine without any problems.

I have attached a image that demonstrates the issue.
[image]
What could possibly be the problem?

PS: here's the output of lshw -c video:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Madison [Radeon HD 5000M Series]
   vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
   resources: irq:46 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0020000-f003ffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f0000000-f001ffff
```

Comment: Try incognito Mode , and see if its still persists.

Comment: @3bu1 still exists in incognito mode. Tried it

Comment: Do you have any AMD Graphics Driver installed?

Comment: This is not a programming issue, it probably belongs on http://askubuntu.com/ or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the graphic drivers.

1. Download latest beta drivers from AMD website.
2. Uninstall ATI drivers:`sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx`
3. Reinstall xorg:`sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon`
4. Reboot.
5. Install new beta drivers:`sudo sh beta_drivers_name.run`
6. Reboot and Chrome works fine.